# New made datasets skips numbers, how do I solve this?

Tags: r, merge, maps

I'm making a map of the Netherlands with for each municipality how high a flood can be. Somehow when I want to merge the dataset of the map with the dataset of the level of a flood, the numbers al go -1, which causes only have corresponding data for 66 values instead of 491. Does anyone know what causes this and how to solve it?

```
# datasets
Dataset_overstromingsrisico <- read_excel("R/eindopdracht/Dataset overstromingsrisico.xlsx")
NL <- readRDS("C:/Users/shaye/OneDrive/Documents/R/eindopdracht/Nederlandse_gemeentes_sp.rds")

# changes the names so merging is possible
Dataset_overstromingsrisico_ok <- Dataset_overstromingsrisico %>%
select(Gemeente = `Gemeente Code`, `Overstromings gevaar`, hoogte = `hoogte overstroming`)

#remove lakes
NL_fixed <- subset(NL, !NL$NAME_1  %in% c("Zeeuwse meren", "IJsselmeer"))
NL_fixed <- fortify(NL_fixed)

#making a new dataset with all the flood heights and id from the mapdata
#i think that the mistake is here
merged_data_p1 <- tibble(id=rownames(NL@data),Gemeente = NL@data$NAME_2) %>%
left_join(Dataset_overstromingsrisico_ok, by = 'Gemeente')


#merging by id
merged_data_p2 <- left_join(NL_fixed, merged_data_p1, by = 'id')

# checking what is the problem
## only 66 are corresponding
sum(unique(NL_fixed$id) %in% unique(merged_data_p1$id))

## min and max seems to be off by one number
summary(as.numeric(unique(NL_fixed$id)))
summary(as.numeric(unique(merged_data_p1$id)))

dput(head(NL)) 
new("SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", data = structure(list(GID_0 = c("NLD", 
"NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD"), NAME_0 = c("Netherlands", 
"Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands"
), GID_1 = c("NLD.1_1", "NLD.1_1", "NLD.1_1", "NLD.1_1", "NLD.1_1", 
"NLD.1_1"), NAME_1 = c("Drenthe", "Drenthe", "Drenthe", "Drenthe", 
"Drenthe", "Drenthe"), NL_NAME_1 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    GID_2 = c("NLD.1.1_1", "NLD.1.2_1", "NLD.1.3_1", "NLD.1.4_1", 
    "NLD.1.5_1", "NLD.1.6_1"), NAME_2 = c("Aa en Hunze", "Assen", 
    "Borger-Odoorn", "Coevorden", "De Wolden", "Emmen"), VARNAME_2 = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_), NL_NAME_2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), TYPE_2 = c("Gemeente", "Gemeente", "Gemeente", "Gemeente", 
    "Gemeente", "Gemeente"), ENGTYPE_2 = c("Municipality", "Municipality", 
    "Municipality", "Municipality", "Municipality", "Municipality"
    ), CC_2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), HASC_2 = c("NL.DR.AH", 
    "NL.DR.AS", "NL.DR.BO", "NL.DR.CO", "NL.DR.DW", "NL.DR.EM"
    )), row.names = c(40514L, 40568L, 40671L, 40872L, 40993L, 
40883L), class = "data.frame"), polygons = list(new("Polygons", 
    Polygons = list(new("Polygon", labpt = c(6.73685884674861, 
    52.9930803174029), area = 0.037455391187902, hole = FALSE, 
        ringDir = 1L, coords = structure(c(6.94647121429443, 
        6.93893623352051, 6.93837785720825, 6.88228797912598, 
        6.88183689117432, 6.86799097061169, 6.86449718475353, 
        6.85912990570068, 6.85603904724121, 6.84917879104626, 
        6.84875488281261, 6.82461881637573, 6.82411813735962, 
        6.82166099548351, 6.79896688461298, 6.78987789154053,  
        6.67311382293707, 6.67321395874035, 6.67775583267223, 
        6.68071413040167, 6.67344188690186, 6.67054700851435, 
        6.66907501220714, 6.66891288757324, 6.66762781143188, 
        6.66326093673717, 6.6588191986084, 6.65731906890881, 
        6.65784311294561, 6.66635608673107, 6.66699886322033, 
        6.67504405975347, 6.67952919006348, 6.6797389984132, 
        6.68712615966797, 6.68741083145136, 6.69687795639049, 
        6.70192193984985, 6.70784282684332, 6.71382617950451, 
        6.7144889831543, 6.71543693542475, 6.72138977050776, 
        6.72286319732672, 6.7244811058045, 6.75767898559582, 
        6.75776481628429, 6.75479507446295, 6.75535583496094, 
        6.75784683227545, 6.76691818237305, 6.76741313934338, 
        6.77148294448853, 6.77279806137096, 6.77296495437633, 
        6.77440690994268, 6.78656005859381, 6.79944419860846, 
        6.82330894470221, 6.82468318939215, 6.84623384475714, 
        6.84677886962896, 6.85272789001476, 6.87175798416149, 
        6.90692281723017, 6.90726089477533, 6.91460180282604, 
        6.91709995269787, 6.93167686462414, 6.93179798126226, 
        6.94496202468878, 6.94647121429443, 52.993621826172, 
        52.9919166564941, 52.9918365478516, 52.9836959838868, 
        52.983627319336, 52.9810371398926, 52.980381011963, 52.9793815612794, 
        52.9788894653321, 52.9777984619142, 52.9777297973633, 
        52.9708251953125, 52.9706802368165, 52.9699783325196, 
        52.9630355834962, 52.9613304138183, 52.9548988342285, 
        52.9547271728517, 52.9394416809082, 52.9391670227052, 
        52.937629699707, 52.9376945495605, 52.9151763916016, 
        52.8993682861329, 52.8990478515626, 52.8841629028321, 
        52.8837471008301, 52.8792457580567, 52.8686981201173, 
        52.875270843506, 52.8755340576172, 52.9050216674805, 
        52.9095802307129, 52.9116287231446, 52.9126930236816, 
        52.9181709289552, 52.9181900024414, 52.9193496704102, 
        52.9446716308594, 52.9465103149415, 52.9500579833985, 
        52.9589729309083, 52.966968536377, 52.9678344726563, 
        52.968173980713, 52.9722099304199, 52.9757995605469, 
        52.9793891906739, 52.9811553955079, 52.9829063415527, 
        52.9847297668458, 52.989143371582, 52.9893836975098, 
        52.9945411682129, 53.0042572021485, 53.0052528381348, 
        53.0079154968262, 53.0123443603517, 53.0158615112305, 
        53.0176391601564, 53.0221099853516, 53.0230369567872, 
        53.0257148742676, 53.02645111084, 53.0278396606445, 53.0390586853028, 
        53.0417785644531, 53.0431175231935, 53.0453529357911, 
        53.0489120483399, 53.0490798950196, 53.050609588623, 
        53.0524559020997, 53.0551185607911, 53.0552215576173, 
        53.0558929443359, 53.0559272766114, 53.0577049255371, 
        53.0612945556641, 53.063045501709, 53.0648612976075, 
        53.0693702697754, 53.0729904174806, 53.073902130127, 
        53.0741043090821, 53.0757102966309, 53.0802421569825, 
        53.0794029235839, 53.0820960998535, 53.0821952819825, 
        53.0838012695313, 53.0836219787598, 53.081382751465, 
        53.0801353454591, 53.080078125, 53.0764122009277, 53.076286315918, 
        53.0721702575684, 53.0699768066406, 53.0654487609864, 
        53.0671615600586, 53.0675468444825, 53.0680694580078, 
        53.0697784423828, 53.0688629150391, 53.0697784423828, 
        53.0810585021974, 53.0837516784669, 53.0846824645997, 
        53.08500289917, 53.0864448547364, 53.089038848877, 53.0891799926759, 
        53.0903434753419, 53.0907211303712, 53.0907669067383, 
        53.0916023254394, 53.0942115783692, 53.0862045288086, 
        53.0713653564454, 53.0705108642579, 53.0562019348145, 
        53.0558395385742, 53.0521392822266, 53.0411911010742, 
        53.0183334350586, 53.0181121826172, 53.013256072998, 
        53.011604309082, 53.0019607543946, 53.001880645752, 52.9944725036622, 
        52.993621826172), .Dim = c(133L, 2L)))), plotOrder = 1L, 
    labpt = c(6.73685884674861, 52.9930803174029), ID = "40515", 
    area = 0.037455391187902), new("Polygons", Polygons = list(
    new("Polygon", labpt = c(6.56134145520507, 53.0010258086308
    ), area = 0.0111914266335567, hole = FALSE, ringDir = 1L, 
        coords = structure(c(6.56990480422985, 6.56098890304571, 
        6.55231904983526, 6.54415798187267, 6.54266500473022, 
        6.5264191627503, 6.52800083160412, 6.51772689819347, 
        6.50579786300659, 6.50120687484753, 6.495276927948, 6.49231195449829, 
        6.49819183349621, 6.49839496612549, 6.50298309326183, 
        6.49557781219494, 6.50471687316906, 6.49583816528332, 
        6.4955620765686, 6.49436616897589, 6.49882984161383, 
        6.49895620346069, 6.50506401062012, 6.50209617614752, 
        6.50211906433111, 6.50822687149054, 6.50378704071056, 
        6.50328779220581, 6.50229215621948, 6.50201702117926, 
        6.50081777572643, 6.50084114074713, 6.50084495544445, 
        6.50088214874268, 6.49663591384888, 6.51469087600708, 
        6.5221910476684, 6.51785898208624, 6.51185321807873, 
        6.50472402572632, 6.51075220108044, 6.50940990447998, 
        6.50963115692144, 6.51409578323364, 6.52001714706415, 
        6.53353214263927, 6.53795623779297, 6.54233407974255, 
        6.54974794387812, 6.5557107925415, 6.56036520004272, 
        6.56192779541027, 6.55902481079102, 6.56058979034424, 
        6.56080007553101, 6.56215620040905, 6.56521892547619, 
        6.56381511688238, 6.57866811752314, 6.57882595062262, 
        6.58019113540655, 6.58316278457647, 6.58382797241211, 
        6.58421802520752, 6.58468294143677, 6.58477687835705, 
        53.0123443603517, 53.0079154968262, 53.0052528381348, 
        53.0042572021485, 52.9945411682129, 52.9893836975098, 
        52.989143371582, 52.9847297668458, 52.9829063415527, 
        52.9811553955079, 52.9793891906739, 52.9757995605469, 
        52.9722099304199, 52.968173980713, 52.9678344726563, 
        52.966968536377, 52.9589729309083, 52.9500579833985, 
        52.9465103149415), .Dim = c(101L, 2L)))), plotOrder = 1L, 
    labpt = c(6.56134145520507, 53.0010258086308), ID = "40569", 
    area = 0.0111914266335567), new("Polygons", Polygons = list(
    new("Polygon", labpt = c(6.87915147676177, 52.9058446536028
    ), area = 0.0364449164908403, hole = FALSE, ringDir = 1L, 
        coords = structure(c(7.02171897888195, 7.0204520225526, 
        7.02001619338995, 7.01825714111334, 7.01793813705444, 
        7.015452861786, 6.97781085968029, 6.97486209869396, 6.97188091278088, 
        6.96880578994751, 6.96421194076544, 6.96088886260981, 
        6.95459794998169, 6.92470693588257, 6.92421293258673,  
        52.8722763061524, 52.8724441528321, 52.8639793395997, 
        52.8649139404296, 52.8649520874023, 52.8622970581055, 
        52.8587646484376, 52.8489341735841, 52.8468246459961, 
        52.8368110656738, 52.8366699218751, 52.8359489440919, 
        52.8357658386231, 52.8246078491212, 52.820339202881, 
        52.8202972412109, 52.8158645629884, 52.8141403198243, 
        52.8123817443848, 52.8052711486818, 52.8107566833497, 
        52.8143997192383, 52.8144912719727, 52.8164024353027, 
        52.8198852539064, 52.8200912475585, 52.8254051208496, 
        52.8255462646485, 52.8290596008301, 52.8291320800782, 
        52.8492813110351, 52.849349975586, 52.8502731323242, 
        52.8519554138184, 52.8583984375001, 52.8588294982911, 
        52.8593139648438, 52.8629722595215, 52.8638153076172, 
        52.8641014099121, 52.8652343750001, 52.8656272888184, 
        52.871971130371, 52.8711204528808, 52.874740600586, 52.8792457580567, 
        52.8837471008301, 52.8841629028321, 52.8990478515626, 
        52.8993682861329, 52.9151763916016, 52.9376945495605, 
        52.937629699707, 52.9391670227052, 52.9394416809082, 
        52.9547271728517, 52.9548988342285, 52.9613304138183, 
        52.9630355834962, 52.9699783325196, 52.9706802368165, 
        52.9708251953125, 52.9777297973633, 52.9777984619142, 
        52.9788894653321, 52.9793815612794, 52.980381011963, 
        52.9810371398926, 52.983627319336, 52.9836959838868, 
        52.9918365478516, 52.9919166564941, 52.993621826172, 
        52.9928588867189, 52.9927062988281, 52.9873046875001, 
        52.9827079772949, 52.9825515747071, 52.9765205383301, 
        52.9751663208007, 52.9645271301271, 52.9638404846191, 
        52.956844329834, 52.956699371338, 52.9550132751466, 52.9499053955079, 
        52.9472007751466, 52.947078704834, 52.9357299804688, 
        52.935344696045, 52.9344177246094, 52.9331665039064, 
        52.9240684509278, 52.9236564636231, 52.9227485656739, 
        52.9226531982423, 52.9179420471192, 52.9176483154297, 
        52.9155349731446, 52.9150848388671, 52.9115409851075, 
        52.9107170104981, 52.9040756225586, 52.9038047790528, 
        52.8992347717286, 52.8990821838379, 52.8745536804199, 
        52.8744087219238, 52.8720512390138), .Dim = c(113L, 2L
        )))), plotOrder = 1L, labpt = c(6.87915147676177, 52.9058446536028
), ID = "40672", area = 0.0364449164908403), new("Polygons", 
    Polygons = list(new("Polygon", labpt = c(6.74601628119528, 
    52.7410173810827), area = 0.039827286216668, hole = FALSE, 
        ringDir = 1L, coords = structure(c(6.81630086898815, 
        6.81541633605968, 6.809000492096, 6.80818700790417, 6.80765485763561, 
        52.6489677429199, 52.6506080627443, 52.6507301330567, 
        52.6535758972169, 52.6537322998048, 52.6620063781739, 
        52.6647491455079, 52.6649856567384, 52.6703071594238, 
        52.67387008667, 52.6789932250977, 52.6792526245118, 52.6812934875489, 
        52.6873283386231, 52.6909332275392, 52.6910820007324, 
        52.6963462829591, 52.7130699157715, 52.7133827209472, 
        52.7127304077148, 52.7127151489257, 52.7134284973145, 
        52.7137107849122, 52.7235832214356, 52.7247161865236, 
        52.7255592346193, 52.7259788513184, 52.7362289428711, 
        52.755729675293, 52.7628784179687, 52.7632179260254, 
        52.7824592590332, 52.7867393493653, 52.7868614196777, 
        52.8010368347169, 52.7974128723145, 52.7972984313964, 
        52.7990798950196, 52.8008880615234, 52.8080062866212, 
        52.8106231689453, 52.8097076416016, 52.8100090026856, 
        52.8150634765626, 52.8249778747559, 52.8276252746581, 
        52.8267097473145, 52.827922821045, 52.8364562988282, 
        52.8436660766602, 52.8472709655761, 52.8488960266114, 
        52.8541984558105, 52.8544235229492, 52.8578033447267, 
        52.8614730834962, 52.8668251037598, 52.8686981201173, 
        52.8792457580567, 52.874740600586, 52.8711204528808, 
        52.871971130371, 52.8656272888184, 52.8652343750001, 
        52.8641014099121, 52.8638153076172, 52.8629722595215, 
        52.8593139648438, 52.8588294982911, 52.8583984375001, 
        52.8519554138184, 52.8502731323242, 52.849349975586, 
        52.8492813110351, 52.8291320800782, 52.8290596008301, 
        52.8255462646485, 52.8254051208496, 52.8200912475585, 
        52.8198852539064, 52.8164024353027, 52.8144912719727, 
        52.8143997192383, 52.8107566833497, 52.8052711486818, 
        52.7990264892579, 52.7987937927247, 52.7804107666017, 
        52.7758674621583, 52.7722282409669, 52.7686882019042, 
        52.7671966552735, 52.7668800354004, 52.7641525268556, 
        52.7623062133788, 52.7614097595216, 52.7587356567383, 
        52.751537322998, 52.7471046447755, 52.7445678710937, 
        52.7426528930663, 52.734489440918, 52.734359741211, 52.7310371398926, 
        52.7308464050294, 52.7265014648438, 52.7004127502441, 
        52.7002639770509, 52.7002563476564, 52.696979522705, 
        52.6966514587402, 52.6903991699218, 52.6867446899415, 
        52.6866416931153, 52.6768569946288, 52.6766548156739, 
        52.6723556518555, 52.6722106933594, 52.6616134643555, 
        52.6543006896973, 52.6542778015137, 52.6530151367187, 
        52.6529846191407, 52.6523666381837, 52.6500282287599, 
        52.6498527526857, 52.649757385254, 52.6496315002443, 
        52.6495704650879, 52.6494750976563, 52.6489410400391, 
        52.6486968994141, 52.6486740112305, 52.6487998962403, 
        52.6503372192382, 52.6518669128419, 52.6519584655761, 
        52.6519660949706, 52.6519851684571, 52.651668548584, 
        52.6515274047852, 52.6513099670411, 52.6507148742676, 
        52.6502418518066, 52.6497688293458, 52.6495208740236, 
        52.6490249633789, 52.648708343506, 52.6477966308594, 
        52.6476936340333, 52.6476707458497, 52.647705078125, 
        52.6477737426758, 52.647933959961, 52.648365020752, 52.6486167907715
        ), .Dim = c(229L, 2L)))), plotOrder = 1L, labpt = c(6.74601628119528, 
    52.7410173810827), ID = "40873", area = 0.039827286216668), 
    new("Polygons", Polygons = list(new("Polygon", labpt = c(6.38184928193449, 
    52.7017355255457), area = 0.030165825992292, hole = FALSE, 
        ringDir = 1L, coords = structure(c(6.45566606521606, 
        6.45556497573847, 6.45556306838989, 6.45550203323376, 
        6.45549488067627, 6.45545816421514, 6.45290803909302, 
        6.45242309570324, 6.44942808151245, 6.4487619400025, 
        6.44040012359625, 6.41872787475592, 6.4179887771607, 
        6.42522621154779, 6.42819976806652, 6.43553400039679, 
        6.42952585220343, 6.43079376220709, 6.43093299865734, 
        6.43238019943237, 6.42342090606689, 6.42372608184826, 
        6.4306321144104, 6.4157128334046, 6.42147588729864, 6.42294406890869, 
        6.4229350090028, 6.42288303375256, 6.42137813568115, 
        6.41836786270147, 6.41575622558599, 6.41537523269648, 
        6.41387081146252, 6.41301393508911, 6.41224813461309, 
        6.41343116760254, 6.41369295120251, 6.41523790359497, 
        6.42848491668713, 6.43450593948376, 6.44491720199596, 
        6.45970916748041, 6.45963096618664, 6.45802497863781, 
        6.47140789031977, 6.47261095046997, 6.47284984588629, 
        6.48326587677013, 6.49514484405518, 6.49509716033936, 
        6.4934258460998, 6.50233316421509, 6.50214004516596, 
        6.50803279876715, 6.51098012924194, 6.51137018203735,           6.50817918777472, 6.49930715560924, 6.48890876770031, 
        6.48155879974377, 6.48162317276001, 6.47888803482056, 
        6.478678226471, 6.47421121597301, 6.47118377685547, 6.46957492828375, 
        6.46212482452393, 6.45030784606928, 6.44736289978033, 
        6.41625499725353, 6.41176700592047, 6.41028594970714, 
        6.40437602996832, 6.402894973755, 6.39987277984619, 6.39390277862555, 
        6.385087966919, 6.38516283035284, 6.38383388519287, 6.38238906860352, 
        6.37799692153931, 6.37659120559692, 6.37219715118414, 
        6.37229299545282, 6.3678989410401, 6.36346817016613, 
        6.35169410705572, 6.34753179550182, 6.34286499023443, 
        6.33551883697521, 6.33405303955078, 6.33409023284918, 
        6.33412599563604, 6.33714818954468, 6.33571720123302, 
        6.33427000045782, 6.33130216598522, 6.32386302948004, 
        6.3223609924317, 6.31787395477289, 6.30600214004517, 
        6.302966117859, 6.30294799804688, 6.29734992980963, 6.29702901840216, 
        6.29409599304194, 6.29265689849854, 6.29119682312023, 
        6.28526210784918, 6.28073978424078, 6.27777194976801, 
        6.27335500717163, 6.27337121963501, 6.27322292327887, 
        6.27347421646118, 6.27492284774775, 6.27644109725946, 
        6.28089284896862, 6.28091096878057, 6.2780938148498, 
        6.28404903411865, 6.28443908691406, 6.28963088989269, 
        6.29001998901379, 6.28413295745855, 6.28418588638311, 
        6.29309320449835, 6.29475212097174, 6.28428792953497, 
        6.28433895111095, 6.28732681274425, 6.28734207153332, 
        6.28311491012573, 6.28300809860235, 6.26514816284185, 
        6.26384210586548, 6.26071119308472, 6.25630283355719, 
        6.2458548545838, 6.23993206024176, 6.23392581939697, 
        6.22501516342174, 6.2251238822937, 6.22500610351568, 
        6.22390985488903, 6.22370195388794, 6.2237977981568, 
        6.22533178329462, 6.24203109741211, 6.23907518386852, 
        6.2450528144837, 6.24964284896845, 6.26020002365118, 
        6.26315879821789, 6.27655982971197, 6.28956508636475, 
        6.29003000259399, 6.30645990371715, 6.30649423599249, 
        6.30641412734991, 6.30075311660778, 6.30677413940441, 
        6.3098921775819, 6.3175158500672, 6.32934522628784, 6.34855604171764, 
        6.3487858772279, 6.35471105575562, 6.36218214035034, 
        6.36217594146734, 6.36210680007946, 6.35905504226696, 
        6.35155916214001, 6.35451793670654, 6.35898303985596, 
        6.3604497909547, 6.36190223693842, 6.35738277435308, 
        6.36050987243652, 6.36325788497936, 6.37224292755138, 
        6.38113117218023, 6.38263797760021, 6.38416481018078, 
        6.38570976257324, 6.39599084854126, 6.40190315246593, 
        6.40910291671753, 6.40942001342785, 6.42148113250732, 
        6.42441701889038, 6.42580509185791, 6.42878103256226, 
        6.44074392318737, 6.44080591201782, 6.43782901763916, 
        6.43787002563471, 6.4453911781311, 6.45566606521606, 
        52.7859497070312, 52.781650543213, 52.7814636230469, 
        52.7787704467773, 52.7784996032715, 52.7769775390626, 
        52.7747383117677, 52.7743110656739, 52.7734375000001, 
        52.7731132507324, 52.7690238952638, 52.7648582458497, 
        52.7647171020508, 52.7556838989258, 52.755657196045, 
        52.7511100769044, 52.7484664916993, 52.7452239990235, 
        52.7448654174805, 52.7430610656739, 52.7413368225098, 
        52.7409133911134, 52.7314071655273, 52.728832244873, 
        52.7207069396973, 52.7197990417481, 52.7194442749023, 
        52.7171058654786, 52.716220855713, 52.7144508361817, 
        52.7136878967286, 52.7135772705079, 52.7126922607423, 
        52.7093772888183, 52.7064208984374, 52.7049407958984, 
        52.7046127319337, 52.7072944641113, 52.7018051147462, 
        52.7053451538087, 52.7061576843262, 52.7069740295411, 
        52.6997528076172, 52.6943817138673, 52.6951675415038, 
        52.693660736084, 52.6933593750001, 52.6941680908204, 
        52.6940689086914, 52.6937980651855, 52.6842079162598, 
        52.6841316223145, 52.6760559082032, 52.6742095947266, 
        52.6732864379883, 52.6732826232911, 52.6730384826661, 
        52.6649208068849, 52.6550903320314, 52.6549606323242, 
        52.6471443176271, 52.6455116271973, 52.6453514099121, 
        52.6192855834961, 52.6191635131837, 52.6168174743653, 
        52.6161613464355, 52.6147994995118, 52.6139564514161, 
        52.6141204833984, 52.6176109313966, 52.6185569763185, 
        52.6195335388183, 52.6187248229982, 52.6214790344238, 
        52.6241722106934, 52.6250305175781, 52.6250953674316, 
        52.6242370605469, 52.6215667724609, 52.6161956787109, 
        52.6144638061525, 52.6163558959962, 52.6172790527344, 
        52.6199951171876, 52.6254043579102, 52.6271858215332, 
        52.6290054321289, 52.6281318664551, 52.6228065490723, 
        52.6210250854492, 52.6192321777345, 52.6192550659179, 
        52.6192779541016, 52.6207084655762, 52.6210975646973, 
        52.6220054626466, 52.6211318969728, 52.6184387207032, 
        52.6184272766113, 52.6166687011719, 52.6166801452636, 
        52.6176223754883, 52.6176376342774, 52.6149673461915, 
        52.6132164001466, 52.6168785095215, 52.6204681396485, 
        52.6276588439942, 52.6294631958008, 52.6321907043457, 
        52.6357917785645, 52.6385154724122, 52.6430053710938, 
        52.7821235656739, 52.7802619934083, 52.7811470031738, 
        52.7829322814942, 52.7856101989747, 52.7792510986329, 
        52.7774085998536, 52.7807922363282, 52.7809410095215, 
        52.7880249023439, 52.7862052917482, 52.781707763672, 
        52.781681060791, 52.7842788696289, 52.7869720458984, 
        52.7869949340821, 52.788787841797, 52.7923202514649, 
        52.7859497070312), .Dim = c(229L, 2L)))), plotOrder = 1L, 
        labpt = c(6.38184928193449, 52.7017355255457), ID = "40994", 
        area = 0.030165825992292), new("Polygons", Polygons = list(
        new("Polygon", labpt = c(6.9670313851746, 52.74943342172
        ), area = 0.0438862572800676, hole = FALSE, ringDir = 1L, 
            coords = structure(c(6.87156152725225, 6.87134170532232, 
            6.87144184112549, 6.86981678009039, 6.86579608917242, 
            6.8657422065736, 6.86446285247803, 6.8644008636474, 
            6.86324787139893, 6.86323404312134, 6.86177396774292, 
            6.86058378219616, 6.86045885086065, 6.85921382904064, 
            6.85870981216436, 6.85176086425787, 6.84073495864874, 
            6.83660316467297, 6.83642005920422, 6.84796714782726, 
            6.84842014312756, 6.84124803543102, 6.84258794784546, 
            6.84436321258545, 6.84896516799938, 6.84770679473883, 
            6.84927892684937, 6.84930896759028, 6.84490585327148, 
            6.84201622009283, 6.84176683425909, 6.84058713912958, 
            6.84516286849976, 6.84081506729126, 6.84249877929699, 
            6.85626506805431, 6.85643815994268, 6.8596181869508, 
            6.86580276489263, 6.86883878707886, 6.87485122680664,  
            7.09234285354626, 7.09269189834606, 7.07204484939587, 
            7.07184267044067, 7.06958770751959, 7.06794166564947, 
        , .Dim = c(194L, 
            2L)))), plotOrder = 1L, labpt = c(6.9670313851746, 
    52.74943342172), ID = "40884", area = 0.0438862572800676)), 
    plotOrder = c(6L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L), bbox = structure(c(6.22370195388794, 
    52.6132164001466, 7.09269189834606, 53.0942115783692), .Dim = c(2L, 
    2L), .Dimnames = list(c("x", "y"), c("min", "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", 
        projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))

dput(head(Dataset_overstromingsrisico))
structure(list(`Gemeente Code` = c("Aa en Hunze", "Aalburg", 
"Aalsmeer", "Aalten", "Ter Aar", "Aarle-Rixtel"), `Overstromings gevaar` = c(0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0), `hoogte overstroming` = c(0, 0.5, 0, 2, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Really hard to answer your question without seeing your data. Can you please attach a sample of your data by e.g. `dput(head(NL))` and `dput(head(Dataset_overstromingsrisico))`

Comment: ofcourse, this is the information for Dataset_overstromingsrisico structure(list(`Gemeente Code` = c("Aa en Hunze", "Aalburg", 
"Aalsmeer", "Aalten", "Ter Aar", "Aarle-Rixtel"), `Overstromings gevaar` = c(0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0), `hoogte overstroming` = c(0, 0.5, 0, 2, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: the other dataset is a large Spatial one so I don't know how to do that, it start with

Comment: new("SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", data = structure(list(GID_0 = c("NLD", 
"NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD", "NLD"), NAME_0 = c("Netherlands", 
"Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands"
), GID_1 = c("NLD.1_1", "NLD.1_1", "NLD.1_1", "NLD.1_1", "NLD.1_1", 
"NLD.1_1"), NAME_1 = c("Drenthe", "Drenthe", "Drenthe", "Drenthe", 
"Drenthe", "Drenthe"), NL_NAME_1 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    GID_2 = c("NLD.1.1_1", "NLD.1.2_1", "NLD.1.3_1", "NLD.1.4_1", 
    "NLD.1.5_1", "NLD.1.6_1"), NAME_2 = c("Aa en

Comment: As you have noticed, comments have a character limit. Can you include the information above in the question?

Comment: it was almost even to long for the original question but I think its okay now